# How to use ruby class Set correctly - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am very confused on how to find the list of friends in my network that were not invited to an event/social using rails method `set`.

- I have `friends` which list all my friends (2 friends in total)
- i have a social/event that i have invited all my friends in my network to `social_invited_friends`
- i am now trying to find the list of uninvited friends `social_univited_friends` by comparing "`friends` and `social_invited_friends`"

> could one kindly advise me how to do this?

This is the terminal

```
2.3.0 :207 >   ap friends = Set.new((inviter.friends).to_a)
[
    [0] #<User:0x007fa6f882adb0> {
                            :id => 2,
                         :email => "emma@gmail.com"
    },
    [1] #<User:0x007fa6f7191db0> {
                            :id => 4,
                         :email => "jesse@gmail.com"
    }
]







2.3.0 :213 > ap social_invited_friends = Set.new(Invite.where(user: inviter, invitee: nil, social: social).to_a.map(&:users))
  Invite Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "invites".* FROM "invites" WHERE "invites"."user_id" = 1 AND "invites"."invitee_id" IS NULL AND "invites"."social_id" = 6
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "invites_users" ON "users"."id" = "invites_users"."user_id" WHERE "invites_users"."invite_id" = ?  [["invite_id", 30]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "invites_users" ON "users"."id" = "invites_users"."user_id" WHERE "invites_users"."invite_id" = ?  [["invite_id", 31]]
[
    [0] [
        [0] #<User:0x007fa6f7191f90> {
                                :id => 2,
                             :email => "emma@gmail.com"
        },
        [1] #<User:0x007fa6f7191db0> {
                                :id => 4,
                             :email => "jesse@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
]
 => nil 
2.3.0 :214 >
```

when i try the below

```
social_univited_friends = friends.difference(social_invited_friends)
```

i get the below results in the terminal

```
2.3.0 :207 >   ap social_univited_friends = friends.difference(social_invited_friends)
[
    [0] #<User:0x007fa6f882adb0> {
                            :id => 2,
                         :email => "emma@gmail.com"
    },
    [1] #<User:0x007fa6f7191db0> {
                            :id => 4,
                         :email => "jesse@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

but i believe i should have nothing in return as i have invited all my friends to the event/social - i should have something like the below:

```
2.3.0 :207 >   ap social_univited_friends = friends.difference(social_invited_friends)
[ ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at `ap social_invited_friends`:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] #<User ...
        [1] #<User ...
    ]
]
```

and then at `ap friends`:

```
[
    [0] #<User ...
    [1] #<User ...
]
```

`social_invited_friends` is a set with one element and that element is a two element array of `User` instances; `friends` is a set with two elements that are `User` instances.

You probably want to use [`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) instead of `map` when building `social_invited_friends`:

```
Set.new(
  Invite.where(...)
        .flat_map(&:users)
)
```

`flat_map` will take care of array-ifying everything too so you can drop the `to_a` call when building `social_invited_friends` too.

You should also be able to do the whole thing inside the database but get it working first.